# Why None as Output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return-value

Sorry I know it's a terribly easy question. But i don't understand why my code returns None

```py
def fun(x, y):
    ''' takes an orderd list and an another number
    as input'''

    if y in x:
        return print("it's in the list")
    else:
        return print("number is not in the list")

print(fun([2,3,4,5], 5))
```

Comment: The function `print` returns `None`. So: `return "it's in the list"`

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a function that doesn't return any value in Python. It only print its own arguments to the user on the screen.

Here is revised code:

```py
def fun(x, y):
    '''Takes an ordered list and another number as input'''

    if y in x:
        return "it's in the list"
    else:
        return "number is not in the list"

print(fun([2,3,4,5], 5))
```

For better readability, it is better to use "long" arguments after "short". Here is my more idiomatic version, just to build better habit:

```py
def contains(item, sequence):
    '''Check if item contains in sequence'''
    if item in sequence:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(contains(5, [2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: you can even reduce it `return  item in sequence`

Comment: wow, thank you so much!! Didn't exactly expect such a nice answer on that kind of question!

Answer (score 0):

You print the return value of the print that is returned from function.

```
def fun(x, y):
    ''' takes an orderd list and an another number
    as input'''

    if y in x:
        return print("it's in the list")
    else:
        return print("number is not in the list")

fun([2,3,4,5], 5)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Helped a lot ot better understand it:)